# Appium logs are displayed with each character on a single line on Terminal but are displaying fine when I run from IDE

Tags: logging, encoding, terminal, appium

When I run Appium from terminal logs are left-sided with each character on a single line. But from the IDE its displaying correctly. I am certain it has to do with the encoding but I really do not know where to start. I have attached a screenshot below for more detailed description.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to many tests were running in parallel, thus, a lot of logs at the same time caused this issue. When I limited the amount of tests to 1. logs were printed fine.